# return array of object with Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift3, alamofire, objectmapper

In my app I am using AlamofireObjectMapper. 
I want to make a method that returns an array of objects. With the help of Alamofire I made a GET request, which gives the response as responseArray.
With using void function array `listOfType` always has values. 
But when I use non-void function that should return array of object `MedicineType`, array `listOfType` is nil. 
So here is my code.

```
func getAll() -> [MedicineType] {
  var listOfTypes: [MedicineType]?;
  Alamofire.request(BASE_URL, method:.get)
      .responseArray(keyPath:"value") {(response: DataResponse<[MedicineType]>) in
         if let status = response.response?.statusCode {
             switch(status) {
                case 200:
                    guard response.result.isSuccess else {
                    //error handling
                       return
                    }
                    listOfTypes = response.result.value;
                default:
                    log.error("Error", status);
              }
           }
        }
   return listOfTypes!;
}
```

Comment: You need to do this in closure, instead of return it, because your call for Alamofire is async so your response will be async

Comment: Look for "Swift + Closure + Async". If you check carefully, `return listOfTypes!;` should be called BEFORE `listOfTypes = response.result.value;` (you can add print)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i said in my comment, you need to do this in closure, instead of return it, because your call for Alamofire is async so your response will be async

This is an example, you need to add your error handle

```
    func getAll(fishedCallback:(_ medicineTypes:[MedicineType]?)->Void){
        var listOfTypes: [MedicineType]?;
        Alamofire.request(BASE_URL, method:.get)
            .responseArray(keyPath:"value") {(response: DataResponse<[MedicineType]>) in
                if let status = response.response?.statusCode {
                    switch(status) {
                    case 200:
                        guard response.result.isSuccess else {
                            //error handling
                            return
                        }
                        finishedCallback(response.result.value as! [MedicineType])
                    default:
                        log.error("Error", status);
                            finishedCallback(nil)
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

**Use it**

```
    classObject.getAll { (arrayOfMedicines) in
        debugPrint(arrayOfMedicines) //do whatever you need
    }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try closure

```
func getAll(_ callback :(medicineTypes:[MedicineType]?) -> Void) -> Void {
Alamofire.request(BASE_URL, method:.get)
  .responseArray(keyPath:"value") {(response: DataResponse<[MedicineType]>) in
     if let status = response.response?.statusCode {
         switch(status) {
            case 200:
                guard response.result.isSuccess else {
                //error handling
                   return
                }
                listOfTypes = response.result.value;
                callback(listOfTypes)
            default:
                log.error("Error", status);
                 callback({})

          }
       }
    }
```

}